# Undefined offset: 0 laravel after deleting language that user has set

Tags: php, laravel

I am new at laravel , php  , the user had specific language to use and I deleted this language from admin panel , this result of course in the user can not login to account and we get this error . I create the lang file again but not working.. now I got this error and need help to fix this issue, it helps me to learn more about laravel and PHP. please help a brother out

```
$lang = DB::table('languages')->where('id', Auth::user()->language)->get();

App::setLocale($lang[0]->lang_code);
```

Comment: The error is occurring since its trying to use property at the 0th index of it. Please add a check before set language.

Comment: why cant call first() instead of get .     $lang = DB::table('languages')->where('id', Auth::user()->language)->first();
    if($lang){
        App::setLocale($lang->lang_code);
    }

Comment: Thanks, John, that worked! appreciate your assistant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
$lang = DB::table('languages')->where('id', Auth::user()->language)->first();
    
if ($lang) {
    App::setLocale($lang->lang_code);
}
```

Comment: `DB::first()` does not return a collection. It returns `null` or an `stdClass` object containing the selected columns and their values. Your example will result in a call to an undefined method.

Comment: Thanks @Dan for the observation, corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked :)  When I logged in to the user account language was switched to EN. :) so now my question! if he chooses another lang and this lang accidentally being deleted, will this rev to EN always ad default lang?

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Since it solve your problem, please accept and upvote the answer. To keep us motivated to help each other.

Now coming to your question, If your default language is set to EN, then it'll get selected. Else you can also set a fallback language in app.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to check either $lang has some data or not then you can fetch its lang code, please try as below

```
if(count($lang)) {
    App::setLocale($lang[0]->lang_code);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your query is not fetching any records (because you delete it), and you're calling the index 0 which is the array key if your query gets some records.
There are several ways to fix this kind of issue.
For example:

```
if($lang->count() == 0) {
  //set default language
  App::setLocale('en');
} else {
 //if has records select the first row
  App::setLocale($lang[0]->lang_code);
}
```

Also, if you want to retrieve a single record I recommend using first() instead of get().